# Why is it that sometimes you have to manually install the Nav Mesh Agent using a Git URL in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

Why did I encounter the need to manually install the Nav Mesh Agent using a Git URL in Unity while working on my horror game project? Initially, I couldn't find the option to add it to the module, and it wasn't until later that I discovered I could do so via a GitHub link. What might have caused this unusual behavior, and how does this workaround function?

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents

I attempted to create a Nav Mesh Agent. I expected that I would be able to add the Nav Mesh Agent to the project module in a straightforward manner, just as I had done with other assets and components. However, I was initially unable to find the option to add the Nav Mesh Agent as I expected. It was only after some troubleshooting that I realized I could manually install it using a GitHub link.

Comment: because its called something other than navmesh now :P its as a package

Comment: Apart from what BugFinder said, it depends on the Unity version you have, as it is no longer installed by default. When you have issues with Unity, it is useful to tell us the version, considering alpha and beta versions also have bugs, the platform you need to build on and so on. Asking things such as "why do some cars have A/C included and others don't" is not really enough to get an answer, since we don't have all details and we don't read minds :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. I understand now.

Comment: @NoahSheikh I updated the answer with references that will help you as things you might know from the Legacy one *MIGHT* no longer apply or would be differently used. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `AI Navigation` package using the Package Manager if you have newer Unity versions as AI content is no longer included by default.

Edit: added some references

[Here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/theres-a-new-navigation-package-in-town.1371633/) is the announcement.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ai.navigation@1.1/manual/index.html) is the documentation. (notice the version combo list which is also Unity-version dependent)

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ai.navigation@1.1/api/index.html) is the API reference. (notice the version combo list which is also Unity-version dependent)